# openGL run slow / process is killed on two textures

Tags: opengl

I am attempting to learn OpenGL, more or less from scratch. I seem to run into an issue when I load two different textures, and use a different one depending on the y-position of the shape. It works, but it appears that computing each frame takes a lot longer than I'd hope for. My computer seems to be completely consumed by that one task, until the window with the OpenGL code closes with the terminal telling me `Killed`. So I assume I am doing something very wrong and stupid.

Here is my **texture shader**:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;

varying float factor; // y-coordinate passed from the vertex shader

varying vec2 intp_texture;

void main(void) {

  vec4 opt0 = texture2D(tex0, intp_texture);
  vec4 opt1 = texture2D(tex1, intp_texture);

  if (factor < 0) {
    gl_FragColor = opt0;
  } else if (factor > 0) {
    gl_FragColor = opt1;
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = mix(opt0, opt1, 0.5);
  }

}
```

Here is what I think is the relevant part of my **render function**:

```
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(texture_loc);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbuffer);
  glVertexAttribPointer(texture_loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

  glGenTextures(2, texs);

  // images for the texture
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data_0);
  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glUniform1i(tex0_loc, 0);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data_1);
  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  glUniform1i(tex1_loc, 1);
```

I have tried running `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data_?);` only at the initialisation. The problem I have then is that then the shader doesn't seem to differentiate between `tex0` sampler and `tex1` sampler.

All and any input would be much appreciated! The full code is on [github](https://github.com/tado-mi/learn-opengl/tree/two-texture), too, if that is helpful.

Comment: It is sufficient to specify the textures once at initialization, but `glActiveTexture` has to be done before `glBindTexture`.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick!